# How to transpile JavaScript library to comply es5 target

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-5

I am using a cookie library https://github.com/ztytotoro/cookies-ts that is compiled to "jsnext" in my Angular project. However, I need it work with es5 target. Is there any way to transpile provided js file in the library to comply es5? I would like to avoid copy-paste "solution"...

Comment: Compile it to es5 instead.

Comment: Sure, the question is how :)